# SQLite not getting copied correctly with Wix installer

Tags: c#, sqlite, wix

I have an SQLite database in my application which is set as content to copy always. I also have a wix installer, and I include the path to my db there too. However, when I try to perform any action, I get missing table errors, because the database hasn't copied over.

Is there anything else I need to do to ensure the db will be available with the application? Everything is working locally, by the way. It's the installed version that fails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of the relevant files from your WiX project?  You are probably looking for *.wxs file(s) containing `<Component>` elements.

Comment: See the answer I posted below - there's actually a separate issue, unrelated to the db file being copied! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have since discovered that there was actually no issue with the database being copied - I had set the application to open once the installer exited and each time, it would throw an exception when I tried to access data. However, when I launched it from Program Files, it worked perfectly. So there's just an issue with my wix installer launching after install, I think - it's a new issue though!